# Error:Undefined reference to function call

Tags: c

```
#include"mylist.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
  struct ListNode *ListHead=NULL;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("input","r");
  int nChunks,i,length,elements,values,t;
  /*insert*/
 if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&nChunks)!=EOF)
    {
      for(i=0;i<nChunks;i++)
    {
      fscanf(fp,"%d",&length);
     testCreateList(ListHead,length);

    }
    }
  while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&elements)!=EOF)
    {
      fprintf(stdout,"%d",elements);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

this is my main file. i am not able to find out where is the error. plus i want to create ListHead as much as "i". and now able to think how to maintain more than one ListHead.

this is mylist.h

```
#ifndef __MYLIST__H__
#define __MYLIST__H__

#include<stddef.h>

typedef struct
{
  struct MyNode *left,*right;
  int chunk;
}MyNode;

struct ListNode
{
  struct ListNode *ListHead;
  int nLength;
};

void testCreateList(struct ListNode *ListHead,int length);

#endif
```

now my CreateList.c file

```
#include"mylist.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void testCreatetList(struct ListNode *ListHead,int length)
{
  struct ListNode *node ,*temp;
  node = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
  node->nLength = length;
  ListHead = node;

}
```

error:

```
gcc testList.c
/tmp/cchD3tuF.o: In function `main':
testList.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `testCreateList'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: and how did you compile?

Comment: You should specify the exact text of the error message. Also: don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: ...and you are not even compiling/linking the file that contains the definition of `testCreateList`? That's the problem right there.

Comment: i reckon you happen to forget to turn the text into code in the last part of your example, that is why include "mylist.h" looks like a title, is the filename mylist.c ? sounds like you forgot to link with mylist.c

Comment: Make sure you don't mix tabs and spaces when pasting code here (using all spaces is generally best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only include header (.h) files containing declaration, don't include .c files with definitions.

That said, the reason it's failing is that you have a typo in the `CreateList.c` file. `testCreatetList` should be `testCreateList` (notice the surplus `t`).

You might consider declaring the `void testCreateList(struct ListNode *ListHead,int length)` in a header and include that instead of the .c file.

There might be other issues with the code - I really didn't look that long at it.

Comment: kindly elaborate for me?

Comment: @Swapna Elaborate on what? The typo should be obvious. For the use of header files please see [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm) or any good book on C. The point is that header files contain function declarations (interfaces) and the c files contain the function definitions (the code).

Comment: I have removed it still im getting error undefined reference to testCreateList

Comment: Did you correct the `testCreatetList` to `testCreateList` in CreateList.c?